# How to efficiently (referring to speed) group extremely large Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I am working with a really large array of size (>10 Million x 2) that is in the following format

```
a = [[1, 1.3],
     [5, 56.3],
     [6, 6.4],
     [12, 18],
     .
     . 
     .]
```

`type(a) = numpy.ndarray`
Basically, column 1 is the index and column 2 is the associated value.
Now,  I would like to group this array based on a list of index I provide.

The groups are just a simple list/array of indices:

```
g1 = [6,1,...]
g2 = [12,5,...]
```

Notice the indices within groups are not in the same order as the indices in my giant array. I could also have more than 2 groups.

Eventually, my goal is to sum up the values of the index in the provided group. But, right now, I am just trying to group this without aging a few years while my code runs.

Result for intermediate step should be

```
a1 = [[6, 6.4],
     [1, 1.3]]
```

```
a2 = [[12, 18],
     [5, 56.3]]
```

Finally the easy part, summing up the values (col 2) for all the indices in the group `a1_sum = 7.7` and `a2_sum = 74.3`.

I am reading `a` from an HDF5 file. From my previous experiences --which is not a whole lot --working from HDF5 directly is slower so I just copy the entire array and work with it. This approach was perfectly fine when my data was smaller, ~500k rows. With this large array, making a copy takes 10 s. I am okay with it but then trying to do what I explained above is just painfully slow.

As you would expect, for loop-ing >10 million rows of the array will take whatever time I have left in this planet. And for-loop is the only way I can think of accomplishing this. I would have to loop through each entry in col_1 of `a` and compare it all lists to find out in which list the index exists and then group. I'm having really hard time to coming up with ways I vectorize my solution approach since vectorizing in Numpy is much faster than looping.

The end result is the sum value. So perhaps there is way to achieve that without grouping?

I would appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't `a[g1]` and `a[g2]` what you are looking for? If you only want the sum and nothing else, then this is not the best solution but at least this is much faster than a loop.

Comment: @JérômeRichard g1and g2 are a list of column one values --not a list/array index. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my post.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The array I was working with consists of  integer index(col_1) and  float values (col_2) which is why I was referring to then entries in g1 and g2 as "index" but they are really just integers that are a subset of col1, not positional index values. Hopefully that clears it up. Sorry for the confusion again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Pandas group-by to get sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/how-do-i-pandas-group-by-to-get-sum)

Comment: @Homer512 The solution presented there is only valid for Pandas dataframe, right? I am working with Numpy arrays.

Comment: You can drop numpy arrays into pandas frames in one line

Comment: If Pandas is only the problem, then it is certainly wise to read previous post about that. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141969 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686381. Are these posts useful?

Comment: Thank you, both! Those previous posts are leading me down the right path and I'm making progress.

Comment: Since you are reading from an HDF5 file, you should consider PyTables. If the data is in a Table object (not an Array object) PyTables can quickly query and return as the desired array of indices and values. There are several (recent) answers that who how to use `Table.get_where_list()` and `Table.read_coordinates()` together to accomplish this task.

Comment: @kcw78 I use PyTables to read in the HDF5 but I typically convert it to Numpy array right away and work with it. Which sounds inefficient and it most likely is. So far, my data size wasn't bad so I didn't have speed issues and I was comfortable working with Numpy only.  Now, I'm realizing how inefficient my methods were. Thanks for pointing me to those two methods. I will check 'em out.

Comment: Here is an answer that shows how to use the 2 functions together: [What is the best way to query a pytable column with many values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74468943/10462884)